What is the fastest way to upcast std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T>>?
Suppose class D is derived from class B. What is the best way to convert a std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<D>> to std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<B>>? The solution should not increment / decrement the std::shared_ptr counter and should not make copy of the std::unique_ptr.
The naive approach does not work:
#include <memory>

struct B {
    virtual void msg() {
        printf("BASE\n");
    }

    virtual ~B() = default;
};

struct D: B {
    D() = default;

    void msg() override {
        printf("DERIVED\n");
    }
};


int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<D>> derivedPtr = std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr<D>>(std::make_unique<D>());
    std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<B>> basePtr = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<B>>>(std::move(derivedPtr));
    basePtr->get()->msg();
}

The compiler says that this static_cast is impossible.

Why do you have a shared pointer to a unique pointer in the first place? Do you know you can convert a unique pointer to shared?

same as a D** cannot be converted to a B** ...  see Conversion of pointer-to-pointer between derived and base classes?

The solution should not increment / decrement the std::shared_ptr counter...   Why not? ...and should not make copy of the std::unique_ptr.  Why not?

I second both questions. Also note, that shared pointer managing a unique pointer is effectively a shared pointer managing a move-only object. What was your intention in writing something like this in the first place?

This is impossible (in any form) because std::unique_ptr<B> and std::unique_ptr<D> are not in any form related by inheritance.
Conceptually this is wrong and this is also the first time I have seen a shared pointer holding a unique pointer. That itself seems like a big red flag on the whole approach and makes it sound like a XY problem.
Why does the shared pointer hold the unique pointer instead of holding the object that the unique pointer holds directly?

This answer is OK but it doesn't explain anything. Look at the comment above if you want to understand the unfixable conceptual problem.

I agree with the others that the premise is unlikely, but granting the premise, let us assume you have:
std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<D>> derivedPtr = /* ... */;

The reason this does not make conceptual sense is that shared_ptr manages the lifetime of the unique_ptr which manages the lifetime of D.
The question becomes: do you need two null states? The shared_ptr can be null or non-null and manage a null unique_ptr. If you do need two null states, I would consider replacing it with std::shared_ptr<std::optional<D>> to be clearer.
If you do not, and it is an artifact of the construction or how the object is handed to you, it is straightforward to get a more useful type:
std::shared_ptr<D> betterDerivedPtr = std::shared_ptr<D>(derivedPtr, *derivedPtr ? derivedPtr->get() : nullptr);

This shares ownership with the original (D is not copied, it's the same D) but removes the likely useless double-null. This is the aliasing constructor.
Then, you can use std::static_pointer_cast.

Despite having a code structure that doesn't make much sense, I'm going to attempt an answer that should at least compile.
Smart pointers are used to control the lifetime of an object.  If you just need a temporary copy of the pointer that won't affect the lifetime, dumb pointers are much more flexible.
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<D>> derivedPtr = std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr<D>>(std::make_unique<D>());
    B* basePtr = static_cast<B*>(derivedPtr->get());
    basePtr->msg();
}


Not sure, but I think Andreev was looking for std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<B>> basePtr = std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr<B>>(std::unique_ptr<B>((*derivedPtr).release()));  Assuming the code is supposed to transfer ownership, which is what I intuited from the not working example.
